# First value of array undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to map some data from my redux but the first value of my array is undefined and I'm not sure how to get past that, because its not an array it only displays  `<div>sdasd</div>` on line 26.

Can anyone tell me how to go about this please?

here is the code I'm using:

```
import '../styles/Item.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTournaments } from '../actions/tournaments';
import Item from './Item';

class List extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchTournaments();
}

renderList() {
  let data = this.props.tournaments;
  const array = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);
  return array.map(tournament => {
    return Array.isArray(tournament.organizer) ? (
      <Item organizer={tournament.organizer} />
    ) : (
      <div>sdasd</div>
    );
  });
}

render() {
  console.log(this.props.tournaments);
  return <div>{this.renderList()}</div>;
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
  tournaments: state.tournaments
};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchTournaments })(List);
```

Here is the redux action:

```
import rooms from '../constants/api';

export const fetchTournaments = () => async dispatch => {
  const response = await rooms.get('/tournaments');

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_DATA, payload: response.data });
};
```

here is the redux Reducer:

```
import _ from 'lodash';

import { FETCH_DATA, EDIT_DATA, DELETE_DATA } from '../actions/types';

export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_DATA:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case EDIT_DATA:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    case DELETE_DATA:
      return _.omit(state, action.payload);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

here is the api I'm trying to map (i have pasted it from a console.log(this.props.tournaments)

```
{undefined: Array(50)}
undefined: Array(50)
0: {id: "a31d5c46-9b7a-4833-bcf1-b0003365895e", name: "Quos Earum Occaecati", organizer: "Aut Omnis", game: "Dota 2", participants: {…}, …}
1: {id: "7b1470c4-86ca-40d3-822d-9753458abdfb", name: "Numquam Ut Vel Perspiciatis", organizer: "Nostrum", game: "Rocket League", participants: {…}, …}
2: {id: "6894a5ed-5334-4979-adfb-fe38871b6c74", name: "Provident Eos Id", organizer: "Odio", game: "Dota 2", participants: {…}, …}
3: {id: "986c9d83-9d76-403d-b1d2-5b47318a3914", name: "Consectetur Quod Sit", organizer: "Consequuntur Eius", game: "League of Legends", participants: {…}, …}
4: {id: "ce0f4112-8228-4a24-9997-5ebe253bc1a6", name: "Enim Eius", organizer: "Dolore Asperiores", game: "Rocket League", participants: {…}, …}
5: {id: "079882a8-35ce-4f01-b142-9ec79eae6b7e", name: "Expedita Nihil Aut", organizer: "Distinctio Quis", game: "Rocket League", participants: {…}, …}
6: {id: "f1f018be-a4c1-44fd-9cd3-97ed44073fbb", name: "Sed Velit Saepe Sunt", organizer: "Quaerat", game: "Rocket League", participants: {…}, …}
7: {id: "6eb102b9-4491-40ae-9480-26c93c0733e5", name: "Aperiam Sit", organizer: "Deleniti", game: "Battalion 1944", participants: {…}, …}
8: {id: "3c2e6b52-2441-4359-a049-3a00022b0337", name: "Rem Quos Ut", organizer: "Voluptates", game: "Dota 2", participants: {…}, …}
9: {id: "f319441a-b06a-44bc-8116-f7cb2e793067", name: "Dolores Reiciendis Qui", organizer: "Voluptate", game: "Dota 2", participants: {…}, …}
10: {id: "8e9943f9-bf7b-410a-8ea5-0e6ae7326ad5", name: "Veniam Delectus Iusto Ea", organizer: "Voluptatibus", game: "Rocket League", participants: {…}, …}
11: {id: "d1adac53-0c48-467a-a66c-39289781dc01", name: "Modi Maxime Reiciendis Similique", organizer: "Quas Aliquid", game: "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive", participants: {…}, …}
12: {id: "3fdd3bef-be4b-4abf-b973-5994895848ce", name: "Tenetur Dolores Sit Doloremque", organizer: "Non At", game: "League of Legends", participants: {…}, …}
13: {id: "65d66436-2cd8-463e-bd6e-3ab3572ff1ea", name: "Pariatur Laudantium Modi Id", organizer: "Expedita Soluta", game: "Dota 2", participants: {…}, …}
14: {id: "56cd5258-57bb-4092-9b50-e48c34fd790a", name: "Maxime Incidunt Molestiae", organizer: "Consequatur Rerum", game: "League of Legends", participants: {…}, …}
15: {id: "5e90ef1d-4f9e-4461-8fa9-eea51bf24437", name: "Ratione Dignissimos", organizer: "Tempore", game: "League of Legends", participants: {…}, …}
16: {id: "f2ffb866-f7e3-4ced-bac6-7dc758e7de60", name: "Vitae Deleniti", organizer: "Eveniet", game: "Rocket League", participants: {…}, …}
17: {id: "08f53ef5-1a74-40ae-a73e-94da5adb0198", name: "Aspernatur Sint", organizer: "Eveniet", game: "League of Legends", participants: {…}, …}
18:
```

The item.js file I'm using to map data into:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/Item.css';

const Item = ({ id, organizer, game, participants, start }) => {
  return (
    <div className="column">
      <h2>Sed Natus Itaque</h2>
      <span> Id: {id}</span>
      <span>Organiser: {organizer} </span>
      <span>Game: {game}</span>
      <span>Participants: {participants}</span>
      <span>Start: {start}</span>
      <div className="buttonBar">
        <button className="button"> Edit</button>
        <button className="button"> Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Comment: Type of your data is object. `{} - object`, `[] - array`.

Answer (score 0):

I just realised I was looking at the payload wrong and that I needed to map it twice to get the value I wanted:

```
  renderList() {
    let data = this.props.tournaments;
    const array = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);
    return array.map(tournament => {
      return tournament.map(item => {
        return <Item organizer={item.organizer} />;
      });
    });
  }
```